# jQuery page fadeIn() only working on index page

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

Thanks everyone, for the quick help! Script now works. I've updated the site and code below. Maybe someone can find this code useful.  :)

---

I've gotten the page (http://www.katmcgo.com) to fade in as desired using jQuery. However, it only fades in on the index page -- all subsequent pages load as normal.

I have the following script in the header of each page (including the sub-pages that are not fading in); it is included in each page using PHP:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        function fadePage() {
            // Target the tags you want to effect with the fade
            var fadingTag = "section";
            var fadingTag2 = "hr";

            var delay = 0;  // Initialize delay - Should start at 0
            var delayStagger = 600;  // Delay stagger - Time between elements fading in

            var fadingNum = document.getElementsByTagName(fadingTag).length;  // Find out how many elements you need to hide

            // Get and fix the overall document height before it disappears (which will happen when elements are hidden) 
            var pageHeight = $(document).height() + "px";
            $("#wrapper").css("height", pageHeight);

            // Hide all targeted tags
            $(fadingTag).css("display", "none");
            $(fadingTag2).css("display", "none");

            // Fade each targeted tag in, one by one
            for (var i = 0; i < fadingNum; i++){

                $($(fadingTag).get(i)).delay(delay).fadeIn(delayStagger);
                $($(fadingTag2).get(i)).delay(delay).fadeIn(delayStagger);

                delay += 350;
            }
        }

        fadePage();
    });
```

I've been racking my brain as to why this is happening, and doing searches to the find the answer, but coming up with nothing...

This page is in the early stages, so I'm just doing dev in Firefox and Safari... fade works in both, but only on the first page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aren't the `<!-- -->` comments causing syntax errors? They should be. Replace them with `//` comments.

Comment: Yeah, those should be //. Thank you! I've updated my code on the page.

Comment: Please don't forget to "accept" the best answer that solved it for you.

Answer (score 1):

install firebug in firefox. your getting an undefined element[0] on all pages except index.php.

Edit:

wrap your s3Slider call inside an if statement checking if the element exists.

```
if( $('#slider').length ) {
  $('#slider').s3Slider({
    timeOut: 3500
  });
}
```

Alternatively you could not output that code from the server if your not on the index page.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error coming from s3Slider.js on all of your subsequent pages. Probably because the slider element does not exist on those pages, but the plugin is still being called.

The fade script probably works fine.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thank you for your help! I should have noticed it.